# Flask send_file / send_from_directory returning 200 status code but not the file

Tags: python, flask, axios

I'm trying to send a file from my Flask app through `send_file()` or `send_from_directory()` without success.

The request returns a response with `status_code=200` but no file is being downloaded. I have verified the functions work as they return errors when the file or directory does not exist

This is the last line of my function. It handles `POST` requests and should return a file after it has been saved.

```
# openpyxl stuff above
wb.save(app.instance_path + '/path/to/file/spreadsheet.xlsx') 

return send_file(current_dir + '/path/to/file/spreadsheet.xlsx')
```

This is what is returned from the server

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2019 20:05:26] "POST /api/admin/export_bookings HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I verified that the file is indeed being created and saved, and I have verified that the above last line returns an error if the path is wrong or if the file doesn't exist.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I am using `axios` to handle my `POST` requests. It seems javascript `POST` requests do not have the ability to return files.

I have found a workaround by returning the `'/path/to/file/spreadsheet.xlsx'` to my javascript as `JSON` and calling `window.open()` with that path.

I then only had to create a standard Flask `GET` route `@bp.route('/path/to/file/<filename>)` that returns the file from the directory by the url using that `send_file()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `form` has `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`?

Did you check if the file exists in the request?

Comment: I see some weird symbols in the `data` part of the response here's a small snippet of it `PK���N�����docProps/app.xmlM�M…��&[Content_Types].xml`

Comment: What's value in `'Content-Type'`?

Comment: multipart/form-data. Maybe worth mentioning, this is a POST request. When I try the same exact function as part of a separate Flask function with a simple GET request, it returns the file without a problem.

Comment: What parameters did you define in the header?

Comment: I tried a variety and none. I went through `content-type`, `mimetype`, `content-disposition`

Comment: I think it might be some problem with the parameters. But check if the path to file is correct using `os.path.exists('path/to/file.pdf')`.

Comment: Path is 100% correct. The `send_file()` function returns errors when the path is not correct. And it also works using the same function in a GET request with the same file in the same directory. The thing is I need a POST request.

Comment: See this code: 

```@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            fp = generate(request)
            return send_file(fp, attachment_filename='weight.fit', as_attachment=True)
        except GenerateError, e:
            error = e
        except Exception, e:
            error = 'An unknown error occured'
    return render_template('index.html', error=error, form=request.form)```

The parameters `attachment_filename` and `as_attachment` are missing in your code.

Comment: Hey thanks but that wasn't it! I figured it out finally. I was using `axios` to handle my `POST` requests through JavaScript. Apparently, you cannot receive files that way. I posted my solution as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this kind of problem.
I am also using flask and send_file() library to send the file to UI for a user to download.

I was just sending file using flask as below.

```
@app.run('/download_any_file',methods=['POST'])
def download():
  path='folder_path_where_file_exist'
  filename='abcde.xlsx' # i am getting this filename from UI
  full_path=path+'/'+ filename
  return send_file(full_path,as_attachment=True)
```

I was getting some response from this API but UI was not able to consume this response for some reason.

[added a snip of Response I was getting with above code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bww2G.png)

After going through documentation https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.send_file.html, i found that one parameter 'mimetype' for excel file(.xlsx) or (.xls) should be passed  as a parameter. Note: mimetype for (.xlsx and .xls) are different plz follow this link to find mimetype for different files
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsofficedeveloper/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2.

I changed my code finally as below:

```
@app.run('/download_any_file',methods=['POST'])
def download():
  path='folder_path_where_file_exist'
  filename='abcde.xlsx' # i am getting this filename from UI
  full_path=path+'/'+ filename
  return send_file(full_path,as_attachment=True,mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
```

Now same mime-type should be used in the UI side to catch and decode the response and put it in excel file to download.
In UI contentType should be the same mimetype which is used in flask send_file()
contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';

This way you can download an excel file.